# Cursor Never goes into $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to set php variable when button is clicked which are some entry modes like addentry, editentry, after lot of research i found jquery ajax is the way to set a php variable on click function. but in debug mode what i saw is the cursor never goes into $.ajax it just skips it

the plugins are

```
<!-- jQuery -->
```

```
<!-- jQuery-ui -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

the html content

```
    <div class = "container">
    <div class = "acdetail">
        <form action = ""  method = "POST"  enctype = "multipart/form-data" class = "frmac" >
            <input type="text" name="acname" id="acname" class="form-control" onfocus = 'SetColor(this.id)'  onblur = 'ReleaseColor(this.id)'></br></br>
            <input type="text" name ="acopen" id="acopen" class="form-control" onfocus = 'SetColor(this.id)'  onblur = 'ReleaseColor(this.id)'></br></br>
            <select name="crdr" id = "crdr" class="form-control" onfocus = 'SetColor(this.id)'  onblur = 'ReleaseColor(this.id)'>
                <option value = "D">Debit</option>
                <option value = "C">Credit</option>
            </select></br></br>
            <select name="yn" id = "yn" class="form-control"  onfocus = 'SetColor(this.id)'  onblur = 'ReleaseColor(this.id)'>
                <option value = "Y">Yes</option>
                <option value = "N">No</option>
            </select></br></br>
            <button type="button" name="addentry" value="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info" onclick = 'BtnControl(this.id,"acname")'>Add</button>
            <input type="submit" name="saveentry" value="Save" id="save" class="btn btn-info" onclick = 'BtnControl(this.id)'>
            <button type="button" name="editentry" value="edit" id="edit" class="btn btn-info" onclick = 'BtnControl(this.id,"acname")'>edit</button>
            <button type="button" name="cancel" value="cancel" id="cancel" class="btn btn-info" onclick = "ClearControl('acdetail');BtnControl(this.id);">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" name="deleteentry" value="delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-info" onclick = 'BtnControl(this.id)'>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery function is

```
    //Button enable disable
function BtnControl(idname,setfocus = ""){
    var curclass;
    switch(idname){
        case 'load':
        case 'cancel':
        case 'delete':
            $("#add").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#save").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#edit").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#cancel").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#delete").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#add").focus();
            break;
        case 'add':
            $("#add").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#save").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#edit").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#cancel").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#delete").attr('disabled',true)
            document.getElementById(setfocus).focus();
            var curclass = 'add'
            break;
        case 'save':
            $("#add").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#save").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#edit").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#cancel").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#delete").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#add").focus();
            break;
        case 'edit':
            $("#add").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#save").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#edit").attr('disabled',true)
            $("#cancel").attr('disabled',false)
            $("#delete").attr('disabled',false)
            document.getElementById(setfocus).focus();
            var curclass = 'edit'
            break;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'entrymode.php',
        data: 'flag='+curclass,
        datatype: 'text',
        success: function(msg){
            $('#m').html(msg)
        }
    })
}
```

the url php page is

```
   <?php
    global $entrymode;
    global $addentry;
    global $editentry;
    global $viewentry;
    global $deleteentry ;
    global $flag ;
    echo '(manoj)';
    switch($flag){
        case 'add':
            $entrymode = $addentry;
            break;
        case 'edit':
            $entrymode = $editentry;
            break;
        case 'delete':
            $entrymode = $deleteentry;
            break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try keeping the breakpoint in the success function on this -> $('#m').html(msg) line

Comment: Well it never goes to success function as it is not entering ajax

Comment: Try adding the error function too, may be some error is coming in your ajax call. See this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax_error on how to add error block in ajax call

Comment: @ManojPatil Open your console. Click on `Network` tab and see if the  ajax request is being made. If `not`, I suggest you to first add `full URL path` in your ajax URL. Also, I presume the key is `dataType` instead of `datatype`.

Comment: @ManojPatil I will not be able to judge your full URL path since you haven't mentioned it anywhere. It should probably be something like `http://your_application_url/entrymode.php`

Comment: I think there is some synthax error which I'm not getting. The debugger comes upto $.ajax the skips the whole ajax part

Comment: There are actually many errors. I suggest you to check the  `console`. Also, why are you redeclaring `var curclass` when you have already declared it globally?

Comment: Well I'm a .net developer just converting one of my app to web,id u can help me with rectifying those error it'll be helpful..in .net what we do is on click of a button we set that entrymode flag and use it through the form..but that simple thing is too much complicated here